# C# Display 2 decimal places

Tags: c#

I cant figure out how to display 2 decimal within this code. Below is a code show when i chose the option from combobox1 and combobox2 then i key any value to textbox2, so it will store the new value. And also if i chose back the same option from combobox1 and combobox2 it will auto take 1/textBox2.Text. But i want to display only 2 decimal places. Can anyone help out with this code?

Thanks

```
            int index1 = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            int index2 = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
            arr[index1, index2] = double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            arr[index2, index1] = (1 / double.Parse(textBox2.Text));       
            MessageBox.Show("Your Current Rate Have Been Updated");
```

Comment: You you can also use Decimal which provides better rounding.

Comment: If this is money, you should probably use decimal instead of double as Fabian suggested since it uses base 10 and can represent monetary values exactly.

Answer (score 5):

This should help:

```
int index1 = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
int index2 = comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
arr[index1, index2] = String.Format("{0:N2}", double.Parse(textBox2.Text));
arr[index2, index1] = String.Format("{0:N2}", 1 / double.Parse(textBox2.Text)));
MessageBox.Show("Your Current Rate Have Been Updated");
```

Look here for the full list of [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Comment: @Chris You are correct.  I was editing that away already.  I had forgotten about the sig fig part of that one.

Comment: I received a error message: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'double'

Comment: Then we've all misunderstood.  If `arr[,]` is storing `Double` data, then your solution is to apply `String.Format()` to the point where you are trying to display the value held in `arr[,]`.  Like so:  `String.Format("{0:N2}, arr[0,0]);`.  In other words, you cannot _store_ just 2 decimals.  You store it all, and then only _display_ 2 decimals.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will provide you with the result with 2 decimal places:

```
arr[index1, index2] = Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", double.Parse(textBox2.Text)));
arr[index2, index1] = Convert.ToDouble(string.Format("{0:0.00}", (1 / double.Parse(textBox2.Text))));
```

This is for your specific code but like others pointed out if its money for better rounding would be better decimal,and the use of Math class.

Comment: It works! I think i miss out the line Convert.ToDouble. Thanks very much :)